# Renaming a session

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, session

In bash I can start a named screen by doing

```
screen -S test
```

If I type

```
ctrl-a A new_screen_name
```

it only changes the title of the screen.  When I do a

```
screen -r
```

I see the session name is still the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `info screen`:

> -- Command: sessionname [NAME]
>        (none)
>        Rename the current session. Note that for `screen -list' the name
>        shows up with the process-id prepended. If the argument NAME is
>        omitted, the name of this session is displayed.
>        _Caution_: Among other problems, the`$STY' environment variable
>        still reflects the old name. Use of this command is strongly
>        discouraged. Use the `-S' commandline option if you need this
>        feature.  The default is constructed from the tty and host names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The command given in the comment was especially what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

### Change name of existing session

You can change the name of an existing session by attaching to the desired session and once inside issuing a shortcut combination and then a command:

```
CTRL-A 
:sessionname NEW_NAME
```

If not sure how to do it, below are detailed steps.

**First, look for your session ID number:**

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    7934.pts-1.myserver (01/14/2014 11:27:25 PM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.
```

**Then attach to your session:**

```
$ screen -r 7934
```

**Press this shorcut combination:**

```
CTRL-A
```

**Now type this command:**

```
:sessionname MYTEST
```

Of course, change MYTEST for your desired session name. Press enter to perform the change.

**Confirm that your session name has changed:**

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        7934.MYTEST     (01/14/2014 11:27:25 PM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.
```

Congratulations!

---

### Assign a name when opening a new session

Choosing a session name when you are creating it for the first time is even simpler. Just use the screen command with -S option followed by the desired name.

**Example:**

```
$ screen -S MY_NEW_SESSION
```

**Confirm the name is assigned:**

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    15832.MY_NEW_SESSION    (01/16/2014 10:08:31 AM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.
```

That's it!